# Applying something similar to Universal Analytics views in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have to configure a GA4 property for a website. In universal analytics I had a view for each 1 of these subdomains but I don't know how to set up something similar in GA4.

the tag is set to [www.xxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxx.com), and I want to measure separately:

- [www.xxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxx.com)
- [www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx](http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx)
- [www.xxxxx.com/xuxux](http://www.xxxxx.com/xuxux)
- [www.xxxxx.com/xxyeie](http://www.xxxxx.com/xxyeie)
- [www.xxxxx.com/ihgei](http://www.xxxxx.com/ihgei)

What would be the correct way to do it in GA4, because before with the views it was very easy to do.

I appreciate any help, thank you very much

I've been trying with comparisons or with filters, but I'm not sure how to set it up or if there is a faster way where I don't have to set that up for each report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with audiences based on users with page views event containing the relevant path. but not 100% sure it's relevant, so I asked the stakc overflow community. We're having very similar questions though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).